# Launch my application (intent) on sms click/view

Tags: android, android-intent

I've developed simple note keeper kind of application, which simply store title and content as text and optionally pictures to save in its database.

I want my application to be launch (app chooser) on click of sms Conversation List when user wants view/edit sms. So that sms content can be imported in my app.
What exactly intent-filter required for it in manifest file ?

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

There is no intent fired upon viewing or editing a SMS. To achieve this you would have to implement a whole SMS Application and have it intercept all the SMS send to the phone.